# Drupal Webform generating radio buttons for select fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-webform

My webform is generating radio buttons instead of select fields. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are editing that field, look down at the very bottom under display and make sure "Listbox" is checked. It is the one that says:

> Check this option if you want the
>   select component to be of listbox type
>   instead of radio buttons or
>   checkboxes.

You didn't say what version of the module you are using, but this should be accurate for all current versions. In the future it would be a good idea to include what version you are having the issue with when asking for help.

Comment: You're a life saver. It never even occured to me that the default type for a "select" field wouldn't be a "select" form element. I'll keep in mind including version numbers in future.